# Comment box not appearing in XFBML Like button linked to Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

On my website I have an XFBML Like button linked to a Facebook page. I set up the app with the website's domain as the App Domain and included the Javascript SDK with the app id.

The Like button itself works, but the comment section does not appear. Inspecting the page in Chrome shows that an iframe appears beneath the like button, but it contains only a script tag with some code. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://www.milliani.com/milliani#portfolio

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the javascript sdk with this code:

```
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
```

It is looking for a div with an id of `facebook-jssdk`, but this div doesn't exist.  Try adding this somewhere in your page:

```
<div id="facebook-jssdk"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this known Facebook bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293075054049400

Basically, one gets this behavior if secure browsing is enabled on the Facebook user's account.